# How to not select weekend dates using month calender when selecting multiple dates

Tags: vb.net, winforms, calendar

I have MonthCalender control on my form and I want to be able to select 10 days (2 business weeks) without selecting any weekends.

Is this possible?

Comment: WindowsForms? WPF? Silverlight? ASP .NET?

Comment: windows forms using vb.net

Comment: I`m afraid that this is not possible with the standard MonthCalender control since you can only set one selected time range. But there are several custom controls out there which should have this feature (including free).

Comment: well this is unfortunate. back to the drawing board

Comment: Could you please explain exactly what you want? There are always many alternatives. For example, you might choose a different control, like `DateTimePicker`. Or you might rely on two or more controls to set the start/end dates. Tons of options. Explain the exact actions which the user is expected to perform and the exact result.

Comment: my expected behaviour from the month calender would be to allow the user to click and select 10 days in a row excluding the weekends.